# how to remove only real duplicates from preg_match output?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, preg-match

Yes I know `array_unique` function, but the thing is that match might have a legitimate duplicates in my search term for example:

```
$str = "fruit1: banana, fruit2: orange, fruit3: banana, fruit4: apple, fruit5: banana";
preg_match("@fruit1: (?<fruit1>\w+), fruit2: orange, fruit3: (banana), fruit4: (?<fruit4>apple), fruit5: (banana)@",$str,$match);
array_shift($match); // I dont need whole match
print_r($match);
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [fruit1] => banana
    [0] => banana
    [1] => banana
    [fruit4] => apple
    [2] => apple
    [3] => banana
)
```

So the only keys that are real duplicates are [0] and [2] but `array_unique` gives:

```
Array
(
    [fruit1] => banana
    [fruit4] => apple
)
```

Comment: why only [0] and [2] duplicates ?

Comment: Because if a regex has a named range it produces two keys, one named and one integer, but unnamed range gives only integer key. And one named and another unnamed range can have the same value by pure chance. So using array_unique is not safe.

Comment: It really does not make sense why only `0` and `1` are duplicates .. what about `3` ???

Comment: [3] is from unnamed range , this duplicate comes from the strings, and I mean only to delete additional duplicates produced by preg_match

Comment: is it necessary to use preg_match ? you can use explode string and create new array using foreach.. and then use array_unique.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344590/php-subpattern-without-numbering-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself, solution is a while loop that deletes subsequent key is one that it is at is not numerical:

```
while (next($match) !== false) {
  if (!is_int(key($match))) {
    next($match);
    unset($m[key($match)]);
  }
}
reset($match);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for your problem:

```
unset($matches[0]);
$matches = array_unique($matches);
```