# simple way to clean a bbcode url

Tags: php

***Waht I have:***
I have an Uploader generate links like below : (this link is on one line)
`[url="http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"][img]http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg[/img][/url]`

link created with 3 different data .
first , **pagelink** : `http://mydomain.ir/direct.php`
second, **image** : `http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg`
third, **thumb** : `http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg`

***What I want :***
I want to give this 3 data to as array on simplest way (speedy way)

***What's problem ? :***
Can use `explode` function but must fine function may a big codes.
no any better way to clean this links on simple and speedy way ? , for example regx .

Comment: try str_split .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: @senthilbp Thanks , but hard to clean with `str_split` and I think not a good result.

Comment: Not sure it's useful to you. [bbcode parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)

Comment: My advise is try experimenting with explode instead of regex as it is much faster.

Comment: @LiamSorsby with a clean like this strings , must use several times `explode` function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$regex = '/\[url="(?<pagelink>(.*))\?(?<image>(.*))\"\]\[img\](?<thumb>(.*))\[\/img\]\[\/url\]/i';
$text = '[url="http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"][img]http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg[/img][/url]';

preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333431/how-to-remove-only-real-duplicates-from-preg-match-output

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt='[url="http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"][img]http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg[/img][/url]';


$re2='(".*?")';    # Double Quote String 1

$result="http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg";
```

Then `split` function by `"?"` as delimiter ..

```
$returnValue = explode('?', '"http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"');

array (
  0 => '"http://mydomain.ir/direct.php',
  1 => 'http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"',
)
```

TRY REGEX ONLINE USING [THIS](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/regexp-editor.php) TOOL

Comment: can give a real test ?

Answer (score 0):

Could a simple search and <strike>replace</strike> substring work for you?

```
<?PHP
   $string = '[url="http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg"][img]http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg[/img][/url]';
   $start = '[url="';
   $middle = '"][img]';
   $end = '[/img][/url]';

// get the link that's between $start & $middle
   $theLink= substr($string, strlen($start)+strpos($string, $start), (strlen($string) - strpos($string, $middle))*(-1));
   // output: http://mydomain.ir/direct.php?http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/137594098272081.jpg
   // do a explode('?',$theLink) here if you need to

// get the img that's between $middle & $end
   $theImg= substr($string, strlen($middle)+strpos($string, $middle), (strlen($string) - strpos($string, $end))*(-1));
   // output: http://cdn1.mydomain.ir/up/thumbs/137594098272081.jpg
?>
```

Comment: good result , but still big code and slowly . I try to find a simplest way with minimum function use .

Comment: Then, I think you have to use the function that it's created for handle `bbcode` as [bbcode_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-parse.php).  Don't know if it's going to be faster ¿?.... (but definitely will be be bigger).  Good luck anyway.